# Remove formatting from outlook

Tags: php, mysql, xml, outlook

I have a little HTML form with a textarea which is saved in a mysql db. 
The problem is that there is often pasted text from emails from outlook and it copies several additional tags from outlook like:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument>  <w:View>Normal</w:View>  ... <![endif]-->
```

I want to remove all the additional tags pasted from outlook before it is saved to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the php [strip_tags()](https://php.net/strip_tags) and see if it removes what you want

Comment: The problem is that I want to keep tags like <br /><b><i> and so on. I just want to remove all the stuff from outlook or word I don't need

Comment: Strip tags allows you to specify what html-tags you want to keep, for exampe: strip_tags($text, '<br><b><i>'); keeps those

Comment: Works! Thank you very much. I didn't know that strip_tags can keep tags. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Patricks glad i could help! Make sure to keep both <br> and <br/>